# Is it possible to wso2is scim interface by using oauth clientid and client secret

Tags: oauth, scim2, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2is 5.4 and want to access the scim2 rest API. I am able to do so by using basic authorization and bearer token, but I would prefer to do it by using client id and client secret. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks 
 Clemens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Client Credentials Grant [1] to get a bearer token and use that to access the SCIM2 endpoint.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Client+Credentials+Grant